# ObjectAnimator duplicates ImageView when animating?

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I'm trying to animate an ImageView on my splash screen on an android app I'm making.

All I want it to do is go up a little bit, it stutters at the start and duplicates when the animation begins, leaving the original image view in place and another version of it completing the animation.

I've just started using Android Studio, so I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something stupid but its making me pull my hair out haha

Here is my onCreate where I have the animation done:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashscreen);


    ObjectAnimator ani = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", -100f);
    ani.setDuration(1500);
    ani.start();
}
```

And the XML for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/madtings" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The app is pretty much done, i'm just trying to make it look pretty upon the startup and have a text input appear in place of where the imageview initially was.

Comment: did you try this? clearAnimation() where animation finished(inside animationListener)

Comment: @Farrokh Sorry i've reworded the question. I dont want it to be there at all, I want the imageview moved up as I've defined (and it does work) but leaves behind the same imageview stuck in its initial position.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this.. did you ever solve this problem?